# How do I stop assembly mips to read \n

Tags: string, assembly, mips, paragraph, mars-simulator

I'm using MARS to program in MIPS Assembly. 
I am reading the string using:

```
li   $v0,8           #take in input
la   $a0, buffer     #load byte space into address
li   $a1, 20         # allot the byte space for string
move $t0,$a0         #save string to t0
syscall
```

And printing it using:

```
la    $a0, buffer    #reload byte space to primary address
move  $a0,$t0        # primary address = t0 address (load pointer)
li    $v0,4          # print string
syscall
```

However, when I print the string, it prints a paragraph attached to the string. I believe that this happens because I press "enter" in order to go to the next step. How can I remove this `'\n'`? It is impossible to keep it because otherwise my program result is:

```
The string you wrote is example
[\n which I didn't want to happen]and it has 8 characters.
```

I wanted it to be: `The string you wrote is example and it has 8 characters.`

Comment: Which part is causing you problem? Just iterate over the string until you find the `\n` and overwrite it with a zero.

Comment: It may help to check the memory content in the debugger, unfortunately the MARS is capable to show memory only in `word`s elements, not `byte`s, i.e. 4 bytes at time in single value, and little-endian way, so string `"123456\n"` is shown as two words `0x34333231 0x000A3635`, while the separate single bytes are `31 32 33 34 35 36 0A 00`, so it takes some focus to read the bytes in proper order from the words in hexadecimal. But when you think about them as single bytes, it's stored in memory "normally" as one would expect, char by char, from left to right.